# Disminuir cantidades en un array

Tags: php, array

Tengo la siguiente function en PHP donde un **array** almacena datos en un loop. Lo tengo condicionado de que si la cantidad es inferior a 0 este agregue el código y la cantidad al **array**

Pero me gustaría preguntar antes si el código existe en mi array, asi este disminuye la cantidad al código ya existente en el array.

Para encontrar un elemento dentro de un array es `array_search` **pero nose como condicionarlo para agregar la cantidad a ese elemento**

```
$array_bpt   = array();

$codpza = '001';
$cantidad = 10;
/*Agrega codigo 001 a array*/
$stock = stock($codpza, $cantidad,$array_bpt);
$array_bpt  = $stock ["array_bpt"];

$codpza = '001';
$cantidad = 4;
/*Codigo ya encontrado en array disminuye 4 */
$stock = stock($codpza, $cantidad,$array_bpt);
$array_bpt  = $stock ["array_bpt"];

echo $array_bpt (0) => Array
        (
            (codpza) => '001',
            (cantidad) => 6
        )

    function stock($codpza, $cantidad,$array_bpt = array())
    {
    
    if ($cantidad_bpt>0) {
        /*Preguntar si existe codigo en array*/

          //$found_key = array_search($codpza, array_column($array_bpt , 'codpza'));
          array_push($array_bpt, array(
              "codpza" => $codpza,
              "cantidad" => $cantidad
          ));
        }
        $out['array_bpt']         = $array_bpt;
        return $out;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde esta definida `$cantidad_bpt`?

Comment: Perdon en declaracion de variable, lo modifico enseguida x $cantidad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes listo, solo hay que descomentar la línea de búsqueda y analizar el valor devuelto, teniendo en cuenta que puede devolver falso o un entero.

Se debe comparar de forma estricta, usando 3 signos `===` porque:

```
false == false  // Verdadero
false == 0      // Verdadero, no es mismo tipo, pero lee el siguiente párrafo
false === 0     // Falso
```

Revisa la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.boolean.php) para saber qué otros valores pueden ser interpretados como falso en una comparación no estricta.

```
function stock($codpza, $cantidad,$array_bpt = array())
{

if ($cantidad_bpt>0) {
      $found_key = array_search($codpza, array_column($array_bpt , 'codpza'));
      if($found_key === false) {
          // No se encontró el valor
          array_push($array_bpt, array(
              "codpza" => $codpza,
              "cantidad" => $cantidad
          ));
      } else {
          // Sí se encontró el valor, hay que sumar cantidad
          $array_bpt[$found_key]['cantidad'] += $cantidad;
      }
    }
    $out['array_bpt'] = $array_bpt;
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks my budda!